# See the value of a playwright variable at any given point in the script

Tags: javascript, typescript, playwright

Is there anyway to see the value of a variable at any given point in a Playwright script? For example, in previous automated testing IDEs I've had the option of either printing out a variable to the console or placing a breakpoint where I could then see the values of all variables, objects, etc in the IDE. I cannot seem to find any way to do that in playwright which has made debugging much more difficult.

Comment: did you try page.pause()?

Comment: yes. Using that liberally right now. The catch is I don't see a way to see the value of variables at that point.